# How to override a method in child class without optional parameter?

Tags: dart

I have some class like this:

```
abstract class Parent {
  void doSomething({dynamic number});
}

class Child01 extends Parent {
  @override
  void doSomething({dynamic number}) {
      ...
  }
}

class Child02 extends Parent {
  @override
  void doSomething() {
      ...
  }
}
```

How can I override `doSomething()` method in class `Child02` without an optional parameter, like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that and the reason can be seen in the following code:

```
List<Parent> list = [Child01(), Child02()];
list.forEach((e) => e.doSomething(number: 5));
```

This is allowed since `Parent` tells us there is an optional parameter to `doSomething` called `number`. But what happens when we end up calling a `Child02` object with this parameter it does not expect? You are not allowed in Dart to send arbitrary arguments (named or not) to a method and see if it is going to be used or not.